Are there any "induced" forces which are repulsive in nature?
For example, London forces and induced dipole forces are both attractive forces. Additionally, when a ferromagnetic substance is placed in a magnetic field of a permanent magnet, induced magnetism makes the substance a magnet which is now attracted to the permanent magnet.
What I am asking is if there are any examples of the opposite, where induced forces end up creating a net repulsive effect rather than a net attractive one.

Yes, diamagnetic materials are repelled from the source of magnetic field (pushed in direction of field decrease). For example, bismuth, copper and even water at normal temperatures are diamagnets (although the effect is weak). Much stronger repulsion effect can be observed with superconductors.

Diamagnetic materials are not a good example of a repulsive force. If you place a superconducting body under a magnetic field, the body will remain suspended at some distance from the magnet. A balance is formed between the weight of the part and the magnetic field potential. What we see is an attractive force.
The same applies to the diamond agent hovering above a magnetic field. If you lift the floating body slightly, it is attracted by the magnetic field until it is in equilibrium again. Only if you force the body closer to the magnet is the force repulsive.
